401 error: Spotify web API upload custom image to playlist
I've been stuck on this for some time now and no matter how hard I search I can't find an answer. I'm trying to add a custom playlist cover to a Spotify playlist but I keep getting a response of 401. I've checked many times that I'm passing the correct access token and playlist ID. I added all the required scope as pointed out on Spotify's API too. I've even tested different images with different KB sizes. Below is my code
const url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${playlist.id}/images`;
        let imgFile = process.env.COVER_PHOTO;
        axios.put(url, imgFile, {
            headers: {
            'Authorization': "Bearer " + token,
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
            }
        })


Error 401 means Unauthorized your token. Not collect assign scopes
OR Not get token by Authorization Code Flow
Image Update API
URL
PUT /playlists/{playlist_id}/images

Scopes
ugc-image-upload
playlist-modify-public
playlist-modify-private


In here
demo.js
const fs = require('fs'); - Adds the ability to read and write files in the program.
const imageData = fs.readFileSync('car.jpg', { encoding: 'base64' }); - Reads the 'car.jpg' file and converts it to a Base64 string.
const accessToken = await getToken(code); - Retrieves an access token using a provided code.
const updateStatus = await updatePlaylistCoverImage(accessToken, imageData); - Sends the encoded image to Spotify to update the playlist cover.
response.send(Image Update Status: ${updateStatus}); - Responds with the status of the image upload process.
const express = require("express");
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require("cors");
const fs = require('fs'); // Required to read files

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

const CLIENT_ID = "{your client ID}";
const CLIENT_SECRET = "{your client secret}";
const PORT = 3000; // {your redirect URI port number}
const REDIRECT_URI = `http://localhost:${PORT}/callback`;
const SCOPE = 'ugc-image-upload playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private';
const PLAYLIST_ID = '{Your playlist ID}'; // Your playlist ID

const getToken = async (code) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(
            'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
            new URLSearchParams({
                'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
                'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
                'code': code
            }),
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                auth: {
                    username: CLIENT_ID,
                    password: CLIENT_SECRET
                }
            })
        return Promise.resolve(resp.data.access_token);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return Promise.reject(err)
    }
}

const updatePlaylistCoverImage = async (accessToken, imageData) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.put(
            `https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${PLAYLIST_ID}/images`,
            imageData,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
                }
            }
        );
        return response.status;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return error.response.status;
    }
}

app.get("/login", (request, response) => {
    const redirect_url = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=${encodeURIComponent(SCOPE)}&state=123456&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&prompt=consent`
    response.redirect(redirect_url);
});

app.get("/callback", async (request, response) => {
    const code = request.query["code"];
    try {
        const accessToken = await getToken(code);
        const imageData = fs.readFileSync('car.jpg', { encoding: 'base64' });
        const updateStatus = await updatePlaylistCoverImage(accessToken, imageData);
        response.send(`Image Update Status: ${updateStatus}`);
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(500).send(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on :${PORT}`);
});

custom image
car.jpg
Base64 encoded JPEG image data, maximum payload size is 256 KB.

Access
http://localhost:{your port}/login

Before

After


@Matt Charnock thank for your acceptance can you up vote too?
